# Error: Can't convert a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function

Tags: r

```
penguins %>% 
  select(species,island,sex) %>% 
  rename(island_new=island) %>% 
  rename_with(penguins,toupper)
```

this is code which is causing error, can someone solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's implied that the first argument of `rename_with` is what has been piped to it, so you don't need to pass `penguins` as the first argument:

```
penguins %>% 
  select(species,island,sex) %>% 
  rename(island_new=island) %>% 
  rename_with(toupper)
```

```
# A tibble: 344 x 3
   SPECIES ISLAND_NEW SEX   
   <fct>   <fct>      <fct> 
 1 Adelie  Torgersen  male  
 2 Adelie  Torgersen  female
 3 Adelie  Torgersen  female
 4 Adelie  Torgersen  NA    
 5 Adelie  Torgersen  female
 6 Adelie  Torgersen  male  
 7 Adelie  Torgersen  female
 8 Adelie  Torgersen  male  
 9 Adelie  Torgersen  NA    
10 Adelie  Torgersen  NA
```